# How to render Direct2D rectangle over Directx12 3D scene?

Tags: c++, game-engine, direct2d, directx-12

I was wondering if anyone would be able to provide some explanation (code snippets would be great) as to how I would render a Direct2D rectangle over a directx12 3d scene that I have. Would I need to render to the dx12 back buffer somehow? If so.. how would I do that?

Comment: Use need to use "D3D11On12". See official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/d2d-using-d3d11on12

Comment: thanks! appreciate the help

Comment: Note that if you want to draw a 'rounded', 'pattern', or other fancy Direct2D rectangle, then interop is your best option. If you want a 'sharp corner' rectangle, it's fastest and easiest to draw it with Direct3D directly.